# Tensorflow Resource exhausted without no resource exhausted

Tags: linux, python-2.7, tensorflow, lstm

i'm training an **LSTM**  on my **GTX 1060 6gb** using **Tensorflow 1.2** in **python**.

On each epoch i save the model with this method:

```
def save_model(self,session,epoch,save_model_path):

    save_path = self.saver.save(session, save_model_path + "lstm_model_epoch_" + str(epoch) + ".ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

Everything works but after nine **epoch** i get **ResourceExhaustedError** when i try to save the model with this method.

I have checked my resources during the training but no resources are exhausted.

The error that i get is the following:

> 2017-06-29 12:43:02.865845: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Resource exhausted:
>   log/example_0/lstm_models/lstm_model_epoch_9.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate10865381291487648358
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 32, in
>      File
>   "/home/alb3rto/Scrivania/Tesi/sentiment_classification/text_lstm/LSTM_sentence.py",
>   line 306, in train_lstm   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/Scrivania/Tesi/sentiment_classification/text_lstm/LSTM_sentence.py",
>   line 449, in save_model   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1472, in save   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 789, in run   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 997, in _run   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1132, in _do_run   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1152, in _do_call
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:
>   log/example_0/lstm_models/lstm_model_epoch_9.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate10865381291487648358
>      [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable/_21,
>   Variable/Adam/_23, Variable/Adam_1/_25, Variable_1/_27,
>   Variable_1/Adam/_29, Variable_1/Adam_1/_31, beta1_power/_33,
>   beta2_power/_35, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/_37,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/Adam/_39,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1/_41, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/_43,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam/_45,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1/_47)]] Caused by op u'save/SaveV2',
>   defined at:   File "main.py", line 28, in 
>       lstm_sentence = lstm()   File "/home/alb3rto/Scrivania/Tesi/sentiment_classification/text_lstm/LSTM_sentence.py",
>   line 18, in **init**   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/Scrivania/Tesi/sentiment_classification/text_lstm/LSTM_sentence.py",
>   line 117, in build_lstm   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1139, in **init**
>       self.build()   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1170, in build
>       restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 689, in build
>       save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 276, in _AddSaveOps
>       save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 219, in save_op
>       tensors)   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py",
>   line 745, in save_v2   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 767, in apply_op   File
>   "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2506, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)   File "/home/alb3rto/anaconda2/envs/tesi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1269, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack() ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback):
>   log/example_0/lstm_models/lstm_model_epoch_9.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate10865381291487648358
>      [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable/_21,
>   Variable/Adam/_23, Variable/Adam_1/_25, Variable_1/_27,
>   Variable_1/Adam/_29, Variable_1/Adam_1/_31, beta1_power/_33,
>   beta2_power/_35, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/_37,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/Adam/_39,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1/_41, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/_43,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam/_45,
>   rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1/_47)]]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When encountering `OOM` or `ResourceExausted Error` on GPU I believe changing(Reducing) `batch size` is the right option to try at first.

> For different GPU you may need different batch size based on the GPU
>   memory you have.

Recently I faced the similar type of problem, tweaked a lot to do the different type of experiment.

Here is the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007984/training-broke-with-resourceexausted-error) (also some tricks are included).

However, while reducing the size of the batch you may find that your training gets slower. So if you have multiple GPU you may use them. To check about your GPU you can write on the terminal,

```
nvidia-smi
```

It will show you necessary information about your gpu rack.